# How to implement HUD (spinner / activity indicator) in ionic 2?

Tags: web-services, http, angular, hud, ionic2

What is equivalent code for `$ionicLoading`. If I have below code snippet how can I set up loading HUD for every http request in a config file. (i.e. It will automatically add HUD when application calls a web-service)

```
makePostRequest() {
    this.http.post("https://domain/post", "ur=kkr")
    .subscribe(data => {
        //Done loading, stop!
    }, error => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error.json()));
    });
}
```

Comment: Want to know too. +1

Comment: How did you get on with the assistance below, @happycoder?

Answer (score 0):

Please check this

```
  let loading = Loading.create({
    content: "Please wait...",
    duration: 3000
  });

     this.nav.present(loading);
```

go through [loading ionic2](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#loading) - documentation